# Tooltip text wraps when there is a space in the text and even if the divisions are correct.how to keep tooltip in single line?

Tags: html, tooltip, angular-ui-bootstrap

If i change tooltip position to right,its coming in two lines.how to wrap the tooltip in single line?

```
<a title="This is a my text.">
My tooltip is getting  wrapped!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a title="This&nbsp;is&nbsp;a&nbsp;long&nbsp;long&nbsp;long&nbsp;long&nbsp;long&nbsp;long&nbsp;long&nbsp;long&nbsp;long&nbsp;long&nbsp;long&nbsp;long&nbsp;long&nbsp;long&nbsp;long&nbsp;long&nbsp;long&nbsp;tooltip&nbsp;text.">
    My tooltip cannot be wrapped!
</a>
```

If i add nbsp to the text its not getting wrapped.yay!